# I'm trying to stop snow script and clear the page after x seconds

Tags: javascript

How can I make the snow clear after a certain time. I've tried using variables and the calling a timeout which switches on to false and stops the makesnow() function but that doesn't seem to clear the page at all.

```
<script language="javascript">


ns6 = document.getElementById;
ns  = document.layers;
ie  = document.all;


/*******************[AccessCSS]***********************************/
function accessCSS(layerID) {                                                                   //
  if(ns6){ return document.getElementById(layerID).style;}     //
   else if(ie){ return document.all[layerID].style; }         //
    else if(ns){ return document.layers[layerID]; }          //
}/***********************************************************/


/**************************[move Layer]*************************************/
function move(layer,x,y)  { accessCSS(layer).left=x; accessCSS(layer).top = y; } 


function browserBredde() {
    if (window.innerWidth) return window.innerWidth;
    else if (document.body.clientWidth) return document.body.clientWidth;
    else return 1024;
}

function browserHoyde() {

        if (window.innerHeight) return window.innerHeight;
        else if (document.body.clientHeight) return document.body.clientHeight;
        else return 800;
}

function makeDiv(objName,parentDiv,w,h,content,x,y,overfl,positionType)
{     
      // positionType could be 'absolute' or 'relative'

        if (parentDiv==null) parentDiv='body';

    var oDiv = document.createElement ("DIV");
    oDiv.id = objName;

        if (w) oDiv.style.width = w;
        if (h) oDiv.style.height= h;


      if (content) oDiv.innerHTML=content;
      if (positionType==null) positionType="absolute";
        oDiv.style.position = positionType;
        if (x) oDiv.style.left=x; else oDiv.style.left=-2000;
        if (y) oDiv.style.top=y; else oDiv.style.top=-2000;


        if (overfl) oDiv.style.overflow=overfl; else oDiv.style.overflow="hidden";
    eval('  document.'+parentDiv+'.appendChild (oDiv);  ');

    delete oDiv;
}

var snowC=0;
var x = new Array();
var y = new Array();
var speed = new Array();
var t=0;
var cC = new Array();
var ra = new Array();



function makeSnow() {
    x[snowC] = Math.round(Math.random()*(browserBredde()-60));
    y[snowC] = 10;
    makeDiv("snow"+snowC,"body",32,32,'<img src="http://i693.photobucket.com/albums/vv296/KIBBLESGRAMMY/CAT/Orange-tabby-cat-icon.gif">');
    speed[snowC] = Math.round(Math.random()*8)+1;
    cC[snowC]=Math.random()*10;
    ra[snowC] = Math.random()*7;
    snowC++;        
}



function moveSnow() {
    var r = Math.round(Math.random()*100);
    if (r>70 && snowC<20) makeSnow();
    for (t=0;t<snowC;t++) {
        y[t]+=speed[t];move("snow"+t,x[t],y[t]);
        if (y[t]>browserHoyde()-50) {y[t] = 10;x[t] = Math.round(Math.random()*(browserBredde()-60));}
        cC[t]+=0.01;
        x[t]+=Math.cos(cC[t]*ra[t]);

    }

    setTimeout('moveSnow()',20);
}

moveSnow();



</script>
```

Comment: You don't need `eval()` for that. Usually, if you're using `eval()` you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`makeSnow` just adds the snowflakes. Stopping that, as you say, does not clear anything. `moveSnow` handles the animation, and calls itself at a timeout. If instead of setting a timeout for the next `moveSnow` each time, you set it up to run in an *interval* just once, you would have an easier time stopping it.

```
window.snowAnimation = window.setInterval(moveSnow, 20);
```

If you add a css class to your snow flakes, it would be easier to target them for deletion.

```
oDiv.className = 'snowflake';
```

Then your clear function could look something like:

```
function clearSnow() {
   window.clearTimeout(window.snowAnimation);
   var flakes = document.getElementsByTagName('snowflake');
   for(var i = 0, l = flakes.length; i < l; i++) {
      document.body.removeChild(flakes[i]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Timeout doesnt help, it helps you only to stop creating new snowdivs, however if you see makeDiv is the one which creates new divs on to the body, if you clear / display:none the divs which got created on makeDiv i hope it will clear all the divs on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the divs that were created.  It might be easier if you give them all some sort of class, like ".snowflake" as you create them (in `makeDiv`), then start removing them from the dom.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to clear the elements created after the time you wanna stop snow falling.
Following code snippet will help you to clear the elements

```
    if(count < 500){
        setTimeout('moveSnow()',20);
    }else{
        var i = 0;
        var elem = document.getElementById('snow'+i);
        do{
        elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
        elem = document.getElementById('snow'+ ++i);
        }while(elem != null)
    }
    count++;
```

you have to create a global variable count.